# Edit IIS DSC PullServer

Tags: powershell, iis, dsc

**Main Question:**
As the title suggests I was wondering if it is possible to edit the iis pull server in such a way that I can capture all requests and run my own code path.

**Some background:**
I have created the IIS pull server following this tutorial from microsoft: [Setting Up a DSC Web Pull Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/pullserver). 
In my DSC configuration I have imported the xWebAdministration module and used the xDscWebService resource to create my PullServer and its endpoints.
I have applied this configuration to my pull server machine and have been able to have my pull client pull configurations from the pull server.

**Goals:**
The goal of my question is to be able to trigger my own code following any pull request from client nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Running custom code on the Pull Server is currently not supported. What custom code are you planning to run on the pull server?

Comment: I was planning on creating code for a maintenance window. The goal would be that the pull server would only supply a configuration if the target node was in the set window. With custom code on the pull server I could capture the pull request and run my logic to determine if the target node is currently in the maintenance window. 
Any idea on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For maintenance windows you could Create custom code in a separate web service or script that triggers LCM reconfiguration tasks on target servers based on defined maintenance Window times/settings. the reconfigure tasks would basically flip Dsc pull on/off and set related settings like reboot policy.